# GAE python google sign in screen beautification

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using the classic way to get user's email

```
class HomePage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
```

My needs are no more than this, except, the google sign in page is rather "ugly". Is there a way to "beautify", for e.g., similar to as in what I have read, OAuth2.0 Google Consent Screen. (Without using it of course)?

For some reasons, I couldn't get Google Consent Screen working (I created client id/secret in developer console, along with consent screen. But I don't know what more need to be done for following code to work:- NotAllowedError)

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth
class HomePage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = oauth.get_current_user("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
```

Comment: The consent screen is hosted by the authorization server and is not part of your application. So you can not and should not "beautify" an OAuth2 consent screen. You usually can add a logo of your app and some information in the developers console but nothing like CSS styles, etc.

Comment: use login with google+ and you can use a prettier popup-based auth screen. much better than the outdated asci-art appengine screen that feels im in DOS

Comment: Yes, it is understandable that Google SSO can't be changed. I am wondering what's wrong with my user = oauth.get_current_user...  code...